# how to add datepicker column in gridview design winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

[image]

I am using winform C#.

In that how can i add the datepicker column in gridview in design method. I can see button, checkbox, link columns. but datetime picker is missing.

And any way to add datetime picker without code. If possible please tell me....

Please help me,..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I display a DateTimePicker in a DataGridView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815677/how-can-i-display-a-datetimepicker-in-a-datagridview)

Comment: Wow, forgotten I'd already answered that question! I'd vote to close, but I'm already out of votes...

Comment: I know the code is here. But I am asking for an option in design mode of visual studio. But its not there. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no built-in option to host a date/time picker control.

However, the `DataGridView` control is very customizable and supports hosting custom controls. All you have to do is extend the `DataGridViewColumn` class to create a custom column, and create a custom cell by extending the `DataGridViewCell` class.

[This how-to article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80.aspx) provides a walk-through of the process.

Comment: Thanks. Its very nice to give link for download.

Answer (score 1):

custom component class for calander columns in datagridview add this to you project

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class CalendarColumn : DataGridViewColumn
{
    public CalendarColumn() : base(new CalendarCell())
    {
    }

    public override DataGridViewCell CellTemplate
    {
        get
        {
            return base.CellTemplate;
        }
        set
        {
            // Ensure that the cell used for the template is a CalendarCell. 
            if (value != null && 
                !value.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(CalendarCell)))
            {
                throw new InvalidCastException("Must be a CalendarCell");
            }
            base.CellTemplate = value;
        }
    }
}

public class CalendarCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
{

    public CalendarCell()
        : base()
    {
        // Use the short date format. 
        this.Style.Format = "d";
    }

    public override void InitializeEditingControl(int rowIndex, object 
        initialFormattedValue, DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
    {
        // Set the value of the editing control to the current cell value. 
        base.InitializeEditingControl(rowIndex, initialFormattedValue, 
            dataGridViewCellStyle);
        CalendarEditingControl ctl = 
            DataGridView.EditingControl as CalendarEditingControl;
        // Use the default row value when Value property is null. 
        if (this.Value == null)
        {
            ctl.Value = (DateTime)this.DefaultNewRowValue;
        }
        else
        {
            ctl.Value = (DateTime)this.Value;
        }
    }

    public override Type EditType
    {
        get
        {
            // Return the type of the editing control that CalendarCell uses. 
            return typeof(CalendarEditingControl);
        }
    }

    public override Type ValueType
    {
        get
        {
            // Return the type of the value that CalendarCell contains. 

            return typeof(DateTime);
        }
    }

    public override object DefaultNewRowValue
    {
        get
        {
            // Use the current date and time as the default value. 
            return DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
}

class CalendarEditingControl : DateTimePicker, IDataGridViewEditingControl
{
    DataGridView dataGridView;
    private bool valueChanged = false;
    int rowIndex;

    public CalendarEditingControl()
    {
        this.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlFormattedValue  
    // property. 
    public object EditingControlFormattedValue
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Value.ToShortDateString();
        }
        set
        {            
            if (value is String)
            {
                try
                {
                    // This will throw an exception of the string is  
                    // null, empty, or not in the format of a date. 
                    this.Value = DateTime.Parse((String)value);
                }
                catch
                {
                    // In the case of an exception, just use the  
                    // default value so we're not left with a null 
                    // value. 
                    this.Value = DateTime.Now;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Implements the  
    // IDataGridViewEditingControl.GetEditingControlFormattedValue method. 
    public object GetEditingControlFormattedValue(
        DataGridViewDataErrorContexts context)
    {
        return EditingControlFormattedValue;
    }

    // Implements the  
    // IDataGridViewEditingControl.ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl method. 
    public void ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl(
        DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
    {
        this.Font = dataGridViewCellStyle.Font;
        this.CalendarForeColor = dataGridViewCellStyle.ForeColor;
        this.CalendarMonthBackground = dataGridViewCellStyle.BackColor;
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlRowIndex  
    // property. 
    public int EditingControlRowIndex
    {
        get
        {
            return rowIndex;
        }
        set
        {
            rowIndex = value;
        }
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlWantsInputKey  
    // method. 
    public bool EditingControlWantsInputKey(
        Keys key, bool dataGridViewWantsInputKey)
    {
        // Let the DateTimePicker handle the keys listed. 
        switch (key & Keys.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.Left:
            case Keys.Up:
            case Keys.Down:
            case Keys.Right:
            case Keys.Home:
            case Keys.End:
            case Keys.PageDown:
            case Keys.PageUp:
                return true;
            default:
                return !dataGridViewWantsInputKey;
        }
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.PrepareEditingControlForEdit  
    // method. 
    public void PrepareEditingControlForEdit(bool selectAll)
    {
        // No preparation needs to be done.
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl 
    // .RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange property. 
    public bool RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl 
    // .EditingControlDataGridView property. 
    public DataGridView EditingControlDataGridView
    {
        get
        {
            return dataGridView;
        }
        set
        {
            dataGridView = value;
        }
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl 
    // .EditingControlValueChanged property. 
    public bool EditingControlValueChanged
    {
        get
        {
            return valueChanged;
        }
        set
        {
            valueChanged = value;
        }
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl 
    // .EditingPanelCursor property. 
    public Cursor EditingPanelCursor
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Cursor;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnValueChanged(EventArgs eventargs)
    {
        // Notify the DataGridView that the contents of the cell 
        // have changed.
        valueChanged = true;
        this.EditingControlDataGridView.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);
        base.OnValueChanged(eventargs);
    }
}

public class Form1 : Form
{
    private DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();

    [STAThreadAttribute()]
    public static void Main()
    {
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        this.dataGridView1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.Controls.Add(this.dataGridView1);
        this.Load += new EventHandler(Form1_Load);
        this.Text = "DataGridView calendar column demo";
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CalendarColumn col = new CalendarColumn();
        this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col);
        this.dataGridView1.RowCount = 5;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            row.Cells[0].Value = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I already saw this code. I am asking for the Design view. Any way its not there.... Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I tried copying and pasting this into my Form1.cs file. It didn't run. what do I need to change in this code to have it work in the form i've created.

Comment: not add this to form.cs just add a component class and paste this code you will get this column as a column type as shown in image you uploaded

Comment: This code is a direct copy from the MSDN site: [How to: Host Controls in Windows Forms DataGridView Cells](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80.aspx). So better to get latest version directly from there.

Comment: @LucWollants it may be a copy, i just answered the question that is all,it is updated nw

Answer (score -4):

You can't add datepicker, but you can create new form with only datepicker, ok and cancel buttons, and open it with button in datagridview

Comment: You can't add datepicker.

It Very funny Answer. Any way Thanks for ur anwser.