# DataGridViewMaskedTextColumn for DataGridView in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn, maskedtextbox

I am trying to mask DataGridView DateTime column, to achieve this I tried custom control made by J Thomas form codeproject [**Link**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26005/DataGridViewColumn-Hosting-MaskedTextBox); after adding in DataGridView and while trying to enter(keypress) datetime value i am getting below error "System.FormatException": [image: System.FormatException]

my winform designer code I made it as below:

```
this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn9 = new JThomas.Controls.DataGridViewMaskedTextColumn();

        // dataGridViewTextBoxColumn9
        // 
        this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn9.DataPropertyName = "DOB";
        this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn9.HeaderText = "DOB";
        this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn9.Mask = "00/00/0000";
        this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn9.Name = "dataGridViewTextBoxColumn9";
```

Is there any other way I can achieve DataGridViewMaskedTextColumn or what should I do resolve this issue.

Comment: First, you should ask the designer of the control. Second, the value you input was obviously not a valid `DateTime` value, I don't think there is any some kind of injection into his code to correct this, all you can do is to handle the event `DataError` of your DataGridView.

Comment: Agree! even after adding DataError event, the DOB field is not accepting any value. Is there any way I can mask DataGridView column. I am very new in winforms development. Please help.

Comment: `DataError` is raised only when the Data is not valid. If you input valid data, your data will be accepted.

Comment: The control you are using seems to not be designed to work with DateTime. Why not using a "DateTimeInput column" instead? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815677/how-can-i-display-a-datetimepicker-in-a-datagridview

Comment: Can someone help me in masking DateTime column "00/00/0000" in DataGridView.