# ComboBox added programmatically to DataGridView doesn't open until after the cell loses focus and then is clicked on again

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcomboboxcell

In a C# WinForms project I am populating a DGV from a `DataTable`. When a user clicks on the cell of one of the columns I need to populate a `ComboBox` and open it **on one click**.

However the CBO will only open when the cell in question loses focus (click somewhere else on the form) and then gets focus back (click in that cell again) - and only if the CBO's down arrow is clicked, not if the CBO's text is clicked. I also need the CBO to open when the CBO's text is clicked.

```
private void dgvCategories_Click(Object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // Prevent code from executing if user clicks on a cell that already has a CBO
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 5 && !(dgvCategories.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].GetType().Name == "DataGridViewComboBoxCell"))
        {
            // Get fields to build New Value query
            List<string> lsNewValuesResult = new List<string>();
            string strCategory = dtCategories.Rows[e.RowIndex][1].ToString();
            string strCompanyName = cboSelectCompany.Text;
            string strQueryGetNewValuesValidationInfo = "SELECT validationdb, validationtable, validationfield, validationfield2, validationvalue2" +
                                                    " FROM masterfiles.categories" +
                                                    " WHERE category = @category";

            // Pass validation info query to db and return list of New Values
            db getListOfNewValues = new db();
            lsNewValuesResult = getListOfNewValues.GetNewValuesList(strQueryGetNewValuesValidationInfo, strCategory, strCompanyName);

            // Create CBO object
            DataGridViewComboBoxCell cboNewValueList = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();

            //Populate the combobox with the list of New Values
            foreach (string strListItem in lsNewValuesResult) cboNewValueList.Items.Add(strListItem);

            // Bind the CBO to the DGV
            dgvCategories[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex] = cboNewValueList;

            var editingControl = dgvCategories.EditingControl as DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl;
            if (editingControl != null) editingControl.DroppedDown = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("dgvCategories_Click Exception: " + ex.Message);
    }

}
```

`DataGridViewEditMode` is set to `EditOnEnter` and `DataGrieViewSelectionMode` is set to `CellSelect`.

The two lines at the end are from the SO Question, "[DataGridViewComboBoxColumn - Have to click cell twice to display combo box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32947475/datagridviewcomboboxcolumn-have-to-click-cell-twice-to-display-combo-box/32947890#32947890)"

I'm not sure what else to try...

Comment: I do not understand the `if` statement, especially the second part with exclamation mark. I thought that following block of code should be executed when the column **is** `DataGridViewComboBoxCell` type.

Comment: @TomášPaul, the `if` statement simply prevents the code from following code from executing if a CBO already exists in the clicked cell - I still want the CBO to open on subsequent clicks after it has been populated, I just don't want/need to populate it every time the user clicks on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider using `CellBeginEdit` event to solve you problem then you can use the next approach:

```
private void dgvCategories_CellBeginEdit(Object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 5)
    {
        if (dgvCategories.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].GetType().Name != "DataGridViewComboBoxCell")
        {
            // Bind combobox to dgv and than bind new values datasource to combobox
            DataGridViewComboBoxCell cboNewValueList = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();

            // Get fields to build New Value query
            List<string> lsNewValuesResult = getCboValues();

            //Populate the combobox with the list of New Values
            foreach (string strListItem in lsNewValuesResult)
            {
                cboNewValueList.Items.Add(strListItem);
            }

            // Store current cell value into ComboBox cell. It is for convenience.
            cboNewValueList.Value = dgvCategories[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value;

            // Cancel current BeginEdit event because it occurs on the cell of type TextBox.
            // Later we'll launch another BeginEdit event on cell of type ComboBox.
            e.Cancel = true;

            // BeginInvoke is needed because:
            // 1. there is a known problem with DataGridView:
            //   - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5114668/why-is-my-bound-datagridview-throwing-an-operation-not-valid-because-it-results
            //   - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26522927/how-to-evade-reentrant-call-to-setcurrentcelladdresscore/26527759#26527759
            // 2. current cell has type TextBox, but we want to change its type to
            //   ComboBox and then begin editing ComboBox.
            BeginInvoke(new Action(
                () =>
                {
                    // Change type of current cell to ComboBox.
                    dgvCategories[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex] = cboNewValueList;
                    // Begin editing of the ComboBox cell.
                    dgvCategories.BeginEdit(true);

                    // Here (after BeginEdit) the type of the cell is ComboBox.
                    // Automatically drop down ComboBox cell.
                    if (dgvCategories.EditingControl != null)
                        ((DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl)dgvCategories.EditingControl).DroppedDown = true;
                }));
        }
        else
        {
            // If current cell is already of type ComboBox then we simply drop down it.
            BeginInvoke(new Action(
                () =>
                {
                    if (dgvCategories.EditingControl != null)
                        ((DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl)dgvCategories.EditingControl).DroppedDown = true;
                }));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is explanation of this approach:

- if `CellBeginEdit` event occurs on the cell of type `TextBox` we cancel this event and then:

  - change type of current cell to `ComboBox`;
  - launch `CellBeginEdit` event for current `ComboBox` cell;
  - automatically drop down current `ComboBox` cell;
- if `CellBeginEdit` event occurs on the cell of type `ComboBox` we simply drop down it;
- we use `BeginInvoke` to change type of the current cell and then begin editing because:

  - there is a known problem with `DataGridView` ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5114668/why-is-my-bound-datagridview-throwing-an-operation-not-valid-because-it-results), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26522927/how-to-evade-reentrant-call-to-setcurrentcelladdresscore/26527759#26527759)) that forces us using `BeginInvoke`:
  - the type of the cell is changed when event `CellBeginEdit` completes.

Approach with `CellBeginEdit` also has the next benefit: it changes cell type either user navigates to the cell by using mouse or keyboard.

---

Another approach is to use `CellStateChanged` event:

```
private void dgvCategories_CellStateChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellStateChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.StateChanged == DataGridViewElementStates.Selected)
    {
        int col = e.Cell.ColumnIndex;
        int row = e.Cell.RowIndex;

        if (col == 5)
        {
            if (dgvCategories.Rows[row].Cells[col].GetType().Name != "DataGridViewComboBoxCell")
            {
                // Bind combobox to dgv and than bind new values datasource to combobox
                DataGridViewComboBoxCell cboNewValueList = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();

                // Get fields to build New Value query
                List<string> lsNewValuesResult = getCboValues();

                //Populate the combobox with the list of New Values
                foreach (string strListItem in lsNewValuesResult)
                {
                    cboNewValueList.Items.Add(strListItem);
                }

                // 
                cboNewValueList.Value = dgvCategories[col, row].Value;
                dgvCategories[col, row] = cboNewValueList;

                // To drop down current cell we must call BeginInvoke,
                // because in the CellStateChanged event handler
                // dgvCategories.EditingControl is null.
                BeginInvoke(new Action(
                    () =>
                    {
                        if (dgvCategories.EditingControl != null)
                            ((DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl) dgvCategories.EditingControl).DroppedDown = true;
                    }));
            }
            else
            {
                // If current cell is already ComboBox we simply drop it down.
                BeginInvoke(new Action(
                    () =>
                    {
                        if (dgvCategories.EditingControl != null)
                            ((DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl)dgvCategories.EditingControl).DroppedDown = true;
                    }));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @marky Does it answer your question, do you need more details or information?