# How can I display DateTimePicker in all cells of a manually generated Column in a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a dataGridview in my windows form application and I'm trying to generate date picker in all cells of a manually generated column. My following code is given below.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            string query1 = "SELECT [Full] FROM database table";

            sqlCon.Open();

            using (SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand(query1, sqlCon))
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command1);
                da.Fill(dt);
                dataGridView2.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
                dataGridView2.ColumnCount = 3;
                dataGridView2.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Test";
                dataGridView2.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "Full";
                dataGridView2.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Date";

              //timedate picker here
              //dataGridView2.Columns[1].
                dataGridView2.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Result";
                dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;
                da.Dispose();
            }
            sqlCon.Close();
        }       
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I display a DateTimePicker in a DataGridView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815677/how-can-i-display-a-datetimepicker-in-a-datagridview)

Comment: No #Wim. I'm trying to generate it manually. Take a look on my code.

Comment: I don't understand how your code relates to your question. Can you explain further?

Comment: @OareasaJoy you want to generate a column manually which is date picker type ....is it so you mean?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work out of the box but it's not all that difficult to subclass `System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn` to host any control of your choosing. On top of that, the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace already contains a `DateTimePicker` class but at this point it's not suited to use inside a `DataGridView`. Let's glue these two together.

We'll start by creating a `DataGridViewCalendarColumn` class:

```
public class DataGridViewCalendarColumn : DataGridViewColumn
{
    public DataGridViewCalendarColumn() : base(new DataGridViewCalendarCell())
    {

    }

    public override DataGridViewCell CellTemplate
    {
        get
        {
            return base.CellTemplate;
        }
        set
        {
            // Ensure that the cell used for the template is a CalendarCell.
            if (value != null &&
                !value.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(DataGridViewCalendarCell)))
            {
                throw new InvalidCastException("Must be a DataGridViewCalendarCell");
            }
            base.CellTemplate = value;
        }
    }
}
```

So what does this class do? It basically says ok, a `DataGridViewColumn` expects a `CellTemplate` for its cells. This is a constraint that makes sure that any column we add to a `DataGridView` adheres to a certain standard.

In essence we're sort of tricking `DataGridView` into accepting a new kind of column containing a new kind of cell. But at this point, `DataGridViewCalendarCell` doesn't exist yet, so we'll continue by creating that as well:

We'll start off by subsclassing `DataGridViewTextBoxCell`, since we have to start with a kind of cell that `DataGridView` does recognize. In this case `DataGridViewTextBoxCell`.

```
public class DataGridViewCalendarCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
{
    public DataGridViewCalendarCell()
    : base()
    {
        // Use the short date format.
        this.Style.Format = "d";
    }

    public override void InitializeEditingControl(int rowIndex, object
        initialFormattedValue, DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
    {
        // Set the value of the editing control to the current cell value.
        base.InitializeEditingControl(rowIndex, initialFormattedValue,
            dataGridViewCellStyle);
        DataGridViewCalendarEditingControl ctl =
            DataGridView.EditingControl as DataGridViewCalendarEditingControl;
        // Use the default row value when Value property is null.
        if (this.Value != null || !String.IsNullOrEmpty(initialFormattedValue.ToString()))
        {
            DateTime parsedDate;
            bool IsDate = DateTime.TryParseExact(this.Value.ToString(), "d/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate);
            if (IsDate)
            {
                ctl.Value = parsedDate;
            }
        }
    }

    public override Type EditType
    {
        get
        {
            // Return the type of the editing control that DataGridViewCalendarCell uses.
            return typeof(DataGridViewCalendarEditingControl);
        }
    }

    public override Type ValueType
    {
        get
        {
            // Return the type of the value that DataGridViewCalendarCell contains.

            return typeof(DateTime);
        }
    }

    public override object DefaultNewRowValue
    {
        get
        {
            // Use the current date and time as the default value.
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

So what this basically does is say to our `DataGridView`: look, I know and you know that you're already accustomed to accepting `DataGridViewTextBoxCell`, because that's how we create grids that can both display and edit text. So I'm going to throw a *kind* of text cell at you.

Furthermore, we'll constrain the input value to a text that is parseable as a `DateTime`.

This creates a reference frame so our grid won't act surprised if we try to create an actual calendar control when we click the cell. So now comes the real magic: the actual calendar control!

We'll subclass the regular `DateTimePicker` control but also make it implement the `IDataGridViewEditingControl` interface, a contract that binds any control that wishes to edit content within a `DataGridView` to a specific set of rules.

```
public class DataGridViewCalendarEditingControl : DateTimePicker, IDataGridViewEditingControl
{
    DataGridView dataGridView;
    private bool valueChanged = false;
    int rowIndex;

    public DataGridViewCalendarEditingControl()
    {
        this.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlFormattedValue 
    // property.
    public object EditingControlFormattedValue
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Value.ToShortDateString();
        }
        set
        {
            if (value is String)
            {
                try
                {
                    // This will throw an exception if the string is 
                    // null, empty, or not in the format of a date.
                    DateTime parsedDate;
                    bool IsDate = DateTime.TryParseExact((String)value, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate);
                    this.Value = (IsDate) ? parsedDate : DateTime.Now;
                }
                catch
                {
                    // In the case of an exception, just use the 
                    // default value so we're not left with a null
                    // value.
                    this.Value = DateTime.Now;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Implements the 
    // IDataGridViewEditingControl.GetEditingControlFormattedValue method.
    public object GetEditingControlFormattedValue(
        DataGridViewDataErrorContexts context)
    {
        return EditingControlFormattedValue;
    }

    // Implements the 
    // IDataGridViewEditingControl.ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl method.
    public void ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl(
        DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
    {
        this.Font = dataGridViewCellStyle.Font;
        this.CalendarForeColor = dataGridViewCellStyle.ForeColor;
        this.CalendarMonthBackground = dataGridViewCellStyle.BackColor;
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlRowIndex 
    // property.
    public int EditingControlRowIndex
    {
        get
        {
            return rowIndex;
        }
        set
        {
            rowIndex = value;
        }
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlWantsInputKey 
    // method.
    public bool EditingControlWantsInputKey(
        Keys key, bool dataGridViewWantsInputKey)
    {
        // Let the DateTimePicker handle the keys listed.
        switch (key & Keys.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.Left:
            case Keys.Up:
            case Keys.Down:
            case Keys.Right:
            case Keys.Home:
            case Keys.End:
            case Keys.PageDown:
            case Keys.PageUp:
                return true;
            default:
                return !dataGridViewWantsInputKey;
        }
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.PrepareEditingControlForEdit 
    // method.
    public void PrepareEditingControlForEdit(bool selectAll)
    {
        // No preparation needs to be done.
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl
    // .RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange property.
    public bool RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl
    // .EditingControlDataGridView property.
    public DataGridView EditingControlDataGridView
    {
        get
        {
            return dataGridView;
        }
        set
        {
            dataGridView = value;
        }
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl
    // .EditingControlValueChanged property.
    public bool EditingControlValueChanged
    {
        get
        {
            return valueChanged;
        }
        set
        {
            valueChanged = value;
        }
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl
    // .EditingPanelCursor property.
    public Cursor EditingPanelCursor
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Cursor;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnValueChanged(EventArgs eventargs)
    {
        // Notify the DataGridView that the contents of the cell
        // have changed.
        valueChanged = true;
        this.EditingControlDataGridView.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);
        base.OnValueChanged(eventargs);
    }
}
```

This is the meat of the code. I realize that it seems a lot, but once you get the hang of this, you can create all kinds of `DataGridView` columns, cells and controls that you'd ever need.

The data you pull in from your database (i.e. the columns that are `DATETIME` on the db side) can be left in string format. The control we just created will parse these strings into dates. So fill your `DataTable`, add your columns programmatically and bind. Assuming you fill your `DataTable` with two columns, one of which contains dates:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("dbTextColName", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("dbDateTimeColName", typeof(string))); // yes string, our code above will take care of the parsing
```

// logic to fill your `DataTable` from db goes here

```
var colText = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
colText.DataPropertyName = "dbTextColName";
colText.HeaderText = "MyTextColumn";
colText.Name = "dbTextColName";

var colDateTime = new DataGridViewCalendarColumn();
colDateTime.DataPropertyName = "dbDateTimeColName";
colDateTime.HeaderText = "MyDateTimeColumn";
colDateTime.Name = "dbDateTimeColName";

yourDataGridView.Columns.AddRange(new DataGridViewColumn[] {colText, colDateTime});

yourDataGridView.DataSource = dt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Capture the onclick event of the grid and if its the column you created then set visible to true on a calendar component OR a DateTimePicker component on top of the grid at the column xy coordinates. Whichever date they choose, place the string value of that date into the cell they had clicked on and hide the calendar component.